# .htaccess редирект или исполнение файлов из нескольких поддиректорий в корне

Tags: .htaccess

Возникла необходимость сделать редирект или выполнение файлов из определенных подпапок в корне сайта. Само решение я нашел, но проблема в том, что подпапок будет много, не хотелось бы каждый случай прописывать отдельно в htaccess. Боюсь что Apache спасибо не скажет. Т.е. сейчас файлы из подпапок 777/000, 777/002, 777/003 вызываются при запросе с главной, но как это оптимизировать, чтобы регуляркой указать все подпапки папки 777 и выполнить переадресацию или выполнение находящихся в них файлов с главной. Например mysite.com/777/001/main.php вызывался запросом mysite.com/main.php. Попробовал самостоятельно использовать регулярные выражения, но, к сожалению, ничего не вышло. Также прошу помочь в оптимизации содержимого файла .htaccess

Ниже привожу содержимое файла htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/777/001/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 777/000/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/777/001/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 777/002/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/777/001/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 777/003/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/777/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 777/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Заранее благодарю за идеи!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^777/\d{3}/admin\.php admin.php [L. QSA]` перенаправит все запросы на `777/xxx/main.php` в главный `main.php` в корне

Comment: если вам наоборот надо чтобы по запросу admin.php отрабатывало что-то из вложенных папок, то тогда вообще не ясно, в какую папку надо передавать управление. Скорректируйте текст вашего вопроса, приведите примеры входящих GET-ссылок, и какие должны для них вызываться обработчики

Comment: Сейчас все работает как надо, файл main.php из mysite.com/777/001/main.php открывается из корня сайта mysite.com/main.php, файл mysite.com/777/002/main2.php соответственно mysite.com/main2.php, но, поскольку подпапок будет около 100 штук, не хотелось бы постоянно использовать конструкцию RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/777/001/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 777/000/$1 [L,QSA], а хотелось бы указать регуляркой все подпапки папки 777.